# Convolution between a sinc and a Dirac comb

Tags: distribution-theory, convolution, dirac-delta

I am not an expert on distributions, but I would like to know if there is a meaningful way to define the convolution

$$ sinc * P_T $$

between $ sinc(x)=\frac{sin(x)}{x} $ and $ P_T = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \delta_{kT}$ where $T$ is an arbitrary real number and $\langle \delta_x,f \rangle = f(x)$.

Defining the convolution in a naive way

$$ (sinc * P_T)(x) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} sinc(x-kT) $$

leads to immediate problems since the sum does not converge for most cases. Is there an more abstract route which lead to a meaningful definition?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: $\lim_{K\to \infty} \sum_{k=-K}^K \frac{\sin(x-kT)}{x-kT}$ always converge

Comment: Ah indeed, thank you! I only considered the definition with 2 limits. I didn't think it would compensate with a symmetric sum.